# How do iMessage sticker packs make revenue?

Tags: admob, imessage

Is there a way to add ads to iMessage sticker packs or are they primarily only paid apps with no ads inside? I use Admob in my apps.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about a business concern related to the App Store, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)

Answer (score 1):

You can make iMessage sticker app. On your app you can keep admob.

1 more idea you can do. Keep feature partner with us. So any 1 can join you and make revenues.

Recently I did such project which raises revenue through stickers and custom emoji keyboards.

Comment: can you explain: a) where the admob is shown? each time a user select a stcker?  and b)i don't understand how this feature partner should work for revenue

Comment: Basically there is ios app, on 1st screen you can put admob and show list of partnering apps. Admob and partners will raise revenue. Partners are just like white label.

Comment: bu to get the stickers i dont need to open the app  - why the user should open it?

Comment: ok - maybe an app where i can also select stickers and share they to other apss like whatsapp

Comment: Did you get admob to work in the iOS extension? I'm trying to do something similar, but have not been able to get the ads to load from admob.

Comment: Yes, please refer this example to integrate admob in iOS https://www.appcoda.com/google-admob-ios-swift/